# It's just too long for SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Update table_name set [xml] = 'some 4322 characters xml' where id_a = 1 and id_b = 123
```

But I keep getting error,

[image]

Table's XML column is ntext datatype

Comment: I'm guessing you have unescaped quotes in your XML string. Check for `'` and replace with `''`.

Comment: @JNK I got whole of jQuery library in it :'( and some other 5 libraries

Comment: I already got this table row in another database, can I just copy that "some how" and import it here

Comment: Just do a search/replace. How are you populating the string?

Comment: If you have it in a field already you still need to escape it. You can do this with `SELECT REPLACE(<xmlfield>,'''','''''') FROM OtherTable`

Comment: Or if you insert it directly you can skip the escapes

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, I have it within another server database's same table, but I am not sure how to export that to this server

Comment: Use my select above, then just copy and paste into the insert.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). And if you're storing XML - please **use** the `XML` datatype!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for suggestion, I am immigrating table from sql 2000 which doesn't used to have xml, anyway I changed this type to xml now, but it still throws error, I changed double quotes to single quotes, still error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all of the issues by putting all xml into variable first and then set,

```
> Declare @doc varchar(6000) = N'<example>.....</example>' Update
> TableName Set Columnn = @doc
```